# Update of nested join not working with an order

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Long time reader, first time poster.  (I did some deep dive searches, and was unable to find anything similar -- Thank you in advance)

I am coding a project using ruby and active record, and I ran into a situation where I'm not able to google search the answer to why two things are happening.  From what I can tell, the first thing is happening because of a known bug with rails.  The second, I do not know.

Here's the mock code:

```
class Object1 < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :object2s, foreign_key: :object1_id, :dependent => :delete_all
end

class Object2 < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :object1, class_name: "Object1"
end
```

Object2 has a unique index for object1_id and date.

I have an update that is failing due to a index violation:

**ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique in Object1Controller#datechange**

Update code:

```
Object2.joins( :object1 ).where( object1: { :id => id } )**.order( obj2_date: ascdsc )**.update_all(
    "obj2_date = " + direction + "(obj2_date, INTERVAL " + difference.to_s + " month)")
```

The index is being tripped on the update without the order (** added above), the dates are being updated in a way that causes the violation.  Elsewhere in the code, I have specified the update order, and it will update them in a way that will not violate the index.  With this Object, adding in the join causes the first issue:

Here's the (mock) SQL generated:

```
UPDATE object2 SET obj2_date = date_sub(obj2_date, INTERVAL 1 month) 
WHERE object2.id IN (
    SELECT id FROM (
        SELECT object2.id FROM object2 INNER JOIN object1 ON object1.id = object2.object1_id WHERE <criteria> **ORDER BY object2.obj2_date ASC**
    )  __active_record_temp
)
```

If I modify the SQL, I can run it in an SQL client where it will work as expected. [Note: I moved the location of the order]

```
UPDATE object2 SET obj2_date = date_sub(obj2_date, INTERVAL 1 month) 
WHERE object2.id IN (
    SELECT id FROM (
        SELECT object2.id FROM object2 INNER JOIN object1 ON object1.id = object2.object1_id WHERE <criteria>
    )  __active_record_temp
) **ORDER BY object2.obj2_date ASC**
```

**Question 1:**
The order is being added to the wrong place.  How do I get it right, or work around it?

I believe this to be related to this bug:
https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/6769

**Question 2:** 
Why is this happening?  ...select id from (select id from table) __temp_table...

```
WHERE object2.id IN (
    SELECT id FROM (
        SELECT object2.id FROM object2 INNER JOIN object1 ON object1.id = object2.object1_id WHERE <criteria> **ORDER BY object2.obj2_date ASC**
    )  __active_record_temp
)
```

Wouldn't it be better for it to be this:  ...select id from table...

```
WHERE object2.id IN (
    SELECT object2.id FROM object2 INNER JOIN object1 ON object1.id = object2.object1_id WHERE <criteria> 
)
```

Removing the need for a temp table just to get the id when it's already getting just the id?

Thanks.

Comment: 1. do I understand it correct, that you only update objects in Object2 ??
So you don't need any Join to Object
2. An Order clause in an Update is useless..

Comment: The where clause was omitted from the generated SQL code blocks, sorry, but you can see it in the "Update Code" code block.  It's attempting to update all Object2s that belong to Object1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't know you could have an entire active record code block inside an active record code block.

This addresses both issues.  Code:

```
Object2.where( id: __Object1.select( :id ).where( :parent_id => id )__ ).order( obj2_date: ascdsc ).update_all(
    "obj2_date = " + direction + "(obj2_date, INTERVAL " + difference.to_s + " month)")
```

Auto generates this SQL:

```
UPDATE object2 SET obj2_date = date_add(obj2_date, INTERVAL 1 month) 
WHERE object2.obj1_id IN (
    SELECT object1.id FROM object1 WHERE object1.parent_id = 15
) ORDER BY object2.obj2_date ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

I really don't get why the Order should matter so much, but simply add

```
LIMIT 18446744073709551615
```

behind your ORDER mBY

```
UPDATE object2 SET obj2_date = date_sub(obj2_date, INTERVAL 1 month) 
WHERE object2.id IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT id FROM (
        SELECT object2.id,object2.obj2_date FROM object2 INNER JOIN object1 ON object1.id = object2.object1_id WHERE <criteria> 
    )  __active_record_temp
ORDER BY obj2_date ASC LIMIT 18446744073709551615
)
```

The cause, why order by are ignored without a LIMIT is simple, rows are per definition unordered so teh ORDER BY is removed without a Limit,

Mysql lets the ORDER BY untouched under special circumstances

```
Object2.joins( :object1 ).where( object1: { :id => id } ).order( obj2_date: ascdsc ).limit(18446744073709551615).update_all(
    "obj2_date = " + direction + "(obj2_date, INTERVAL " + difference.to_s + " month)")
```

Comment: Order matters because of the index.  If the data is [ [ jan,1 ], [ feb, 3] ] and I need to move the month forward one, updating the jan record first will make two feb months, where as if I update the feb record first, it becomes march, so when I do the jan record it is allowed by the index.     Where do I put the limit in the activerecord code?  The SQL above is generated by the server, not something I type in.

Comment: sorry i thought you knew the ruby code simply add **.limit(18446744073709551615)** like in the updated answer

Comment: If I add that **.limit(18446744073709551615)** in, the code still throws an error:  **ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique in CodeController#datechange**

Comment: New generated SQL  ```UPDATE object2 SET obj2_date = date_sub(obj2_date, INTERVAL 1 month) 
WHERE object2.id IN (
 SELECT id FROM (
  SELECT object2.id FROM object2 INNER JOIN object1 ON object1.id = object2.object1_id WHERE object1.id = 15  ORDER BY object2.obj2_date ASC LIMIT 18446744073709551615
 )  __active_record_temp
) ```

Comment: You problem is that you need only DISTINCT id, it seems you inner join procudes doubles or more ids so you have to make the ids unique

Comment: It's not though.  The issue is that the index only allows one record per date.  If you update the records in the right order, there is no index violation.  In the OP, I showed the SQL that works, when the order is placed in the right place, the whole SQL executes.

Comment: i see i have changed the Select a bit, you need then to sort the id, so you need teh date also from the subselect, i don't know really how that should effect, but that should give you the desired result

Comment: The SQL I put in the OP gives the desired results (order is moved out one more level).  My question is/was how do I get the order to move from where it is in the generated SQL to where it should be in SQL that works.   The work around is that I loop through each Object1, and update all the Object2 with the order.  [Which results in 1+N SQL executions vs the 1 SQL when the order is moved]

Comment: like i explained in the answer, all subquery iánd you SELECT id is such one is unordered, to oder it you must ordr and limit it, so that the the order is used in the in clause, so take it there is **no other** way,

Comment: The subquery doesn’t need to be ordered.  The query in my OP works exactly as it should, I don’t mean to contradict you, but there is another way.   To be clear here, I am not looking for help with the SQL, I’m looking for how I change the code to generate the SQL I included.